# Is the maximum of the absolute value of the second derivative always smaller than the maximum of the absolute value of the 1st derivative?

Tags: calculus, functions

Assume a function $f(x)$ is differentiable, is the maximum of the absolute value of the second derivative always smaller than the maximum of the absolute value of the 1st derivative?
$$\max\left(\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right) > \max\left(\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}\right)$$ over $x$?

Comment: try with $f'(x) = \sin(x^2)$

Comment: $f(x)=0$ would have a constant value on each side for another simple example.

Comment: Unless you meant to say $\ge$ rather than $>$, what about plain old $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: both derivatives have a max of $1$

Comment: @RossMillikan Ergo $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: and we don't care that $|f''(0)|$ is $>$ or not than $|f'(0)|$ when writing than if $f$ is $C^n$ then $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!} x^k+o(x^n)$ as $x \to 0$

Comment: @user1952009 can you tell me why if $f$ is $C^n$ then the remaining term in your expression of $f(x)$ is $o(x^n)$ as $x->0$? Why can't it be something else like $o(x^{n+1})$

Comment: @kww are you idiot ?  you didn't understand what means $o(x^n)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 yes I found out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

No.  A unit argument can show it.  Assuming $f$ is dimensionless and $x$ has units of length, $f'$ has dimensions of inverse length and $f''$ has dimensions of inverse length$^2$, so you can't compare them.  The numeric comparison will depend on the units of measure of $x$.

For a specific example, take $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ then $\max f'=2, \max f''=4$

Comment: why do the taylor series of sin(2x) at x = 0 still exist if the derivative is larger and larger for higher order derivative?

Comment: the method in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200066/finding-for-what-x-values-the-error-of-sin-x-approx-x-frac-x3-6-is-smal?rq=1 seem not to work for $sin(2x)$ because the values of the derivative gets higher and higher at $x =0$.

Comment: The maximum of the derivative increases without bound, but close enough to $0$ the powers of $x$ will dominate.  The factorials in the denominator grow even faster, so the Taylor series converges everywhere in the complex plane.

Comment: To follow that question, you can use the alternating series theorem, which says as long as the terms are decreasing the error is of the same sign as the first neglected term and smaller in value.  As I said, the factorials in the denominator will dominate over the $(2x)^n$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Simple counterexample: consider the function 
$$f(x)=x^2$$
on the interval $(0,\frac{1}{2})$.